# CreditsState.hx:85 : characters 6 - 11 : Expected , or ]

Tags: haxe, object-expected

So im trying to code some credits to a game, and when i try to compile it, errors like "Expected , near ]" appears. Heres the code if you need (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDFW9.png)

I followed a YouTube tutorial to make credits and i followed them correctly, the error just pops up everytime I edit soemthing on the code

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language.

Comment: You may also want to use something that does syntax highlighting for the language (which would have made your oversight more obvious), such as HaxeDevelop or Visual Studio Code (with the Haxe plugin).

Answer (score 2):

You lost the closing quotation mark after **['VS Jaimi** and the commas between [] and **'Jaimi,'**. Please check the syntax.